# UITableView crashes when datasource is connected in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, interface-builder, ios-simulator

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)cijferTableView{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)cijferTableView:(UITableView *)cijferTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [marksArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)cijferTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [marksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

I have a marksArray which is filled with strings. 
The code worked fine until a quarter of an hour ago but since then it has been crashing when I load the view this code is in, without me changing anything.

When I, in interface builder, disconnect the datasource however, the view is loaded properly without a crash. But of course, it won't fill the table in that case.

What did I do wrong?

---

Update:

The error the console gives is terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Also, i didnt exactly add anything into marksArray just yet. To test, i just have this:

```
 //.h

NSMutableArray *marksArray;
```

and

```
//.m

marksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil;
```

Comment: Could you please post the error the console is giving you?

Comment: Actually, can also you post the code where you initialize marksArray? It sounds like a you're maybe accessing some invalid data.

Comment: @Jensen2k @Jablair Updated the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You forgot to retain marksArray

2) Weird names for dataSource methods ('cijfer' stuff instead of tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:). They will not work.

Comment: Oh my god I'm a moron. You're right, i forgot to retain marksArray. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you did a search and replace for "tableView" with cijferTableView and in doing so you renamed the methods, which will cause this to break. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)cijferTableView:(UITableView *)cijferTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [marksArray count];
}
```

should be...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)cijferTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [marksArray count];
}
```

Comment: Wow, did I ever just skim the question - jumped right to the array and didn't actually read the code. To expand on Kenny's answer, you're claiming you implement UITableViewDataSource, but you're not implementing the methods - essentially, you're in breach of the contract. As a result, the app is attempting to call the UITableViewDataSource methods and throwing a runtime error because your controller doesn't implement the selector.

Comment: Can you update your post and add your new code? Do you get any sort of error message on crash?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you renaming your delegate methods? Maybe those are causing some of your problems?